# do i need to explicitly use "autowire" in xml file to autowire in Spring web app

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I tried so much and then find out the i didn't use `autowire = "byName"` in bean  and thats why it was not autowriring.

1) i want to ask that is that the same case with using @Resource. i mean do i need to write autowire in bean for that

2)But in some of files @Resource is working without writing autowire in beans

Comment: Look for annotation based config in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to ask that is that the same case with using @Resource. i mean do i need to write autowire in bean for that

The effect is essentially the same. The `@Resource` provides a decoupling from spring as it's in the `javax` package. `@Resource` is also equivalent of using `@Autowired` in combination with `@Qualifier`

> But in some of files @Resource is working without writing autowire in beans

Yes, that's how it works. It does `"autowire"-by-name` when applied like `@Resource("someBean")` regardless of any value `autowire = "byName"`.

Comment: there is one bean in web app which does not autowire using @resource unless i use autowire="ByName" in that bean xml file . But same bean work with autowire in other file . how can i know which thing is causing problem

Comment: @Pasha, unfortunately only through loggig (enable `debug` logging for spring, e.g., using `log4j`).

Comment: i tried everything for about last6 days but could not find out , then  i tried autowire and it worked but don't know why

Answer (score 1):

When you autowire by name (default is by type within the @Autowired annotation), then there is basically no difference between it and @Resource. You can either choose to define those autowired beans in xml, or you just add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="service"/>
```

to your application-context.xml, where service (for example) is your package to tell spring where to scan for annotations in your project. Then it will automatically find those annotated classes (within that package).

Answer (score 0):

The `@Resource` annotation doesn't use autowiring, since you specify the name of the resource you want to wire in. So you don't need to specify any particular autowire value on the bean.

Even if you use the `@Autowire` annotation, you shouldn't need to set the `autowire` attribute. You use the attribute *or* the annotation but you don't need both.